# Vary a variable-name in a for loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im looking for help with trying to vary a variable-name in a for loop:

```
For b = 1 To Count

    ' the below image_var(b) varible needs to vary on each iteration'
    Dim image_var(b) As New LinkedResource(Server.MapPath(myArray(b-1)))

    ' need also to have the b in myArray(b-1) bit work through the loop too'
    ' that is I''m after the array index b minus 1'

    image_var(b).ContentId = "imageContentId_" + b.ToString

    ' add the LinkedResource to the appropriate view'
    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(image_var(b))

Next b
```

Thanks in advance as I can't logon to accept an answer...

---

Thanks Guffa - my pics are now making it through to the email and showing up.

The (b) in the image_var(b) was just a stub for me too - till I found the code I was after... Am new and didn't even know/realise that it made an array... am a nobb.

Thanks again...

Comment: You have to login to write a question, what exactly is with "I can't logon to accept an answer..."?

Comment: I don't understand your question either, nor what you're saying about the fact that you can't longon to accept the answer...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to ask here, but first things first - why are you declaring an array inside the loop? It seems totally unnecessary to what you're trying to do and is incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you think that you need a separate variable for each instance. The variable just holds a reference to the object, it doesn't matter at all what you call the variable. You can just reuse the same variable for each of the objects:

```
For b = 1 To Count

  Dim image As New LinkedResource(Server.MapPath(myArray(b-1)))

  image.ContentId = "imageContentId_" + b.ToString

  ' add the LinkedResource to the appropriate view'
  htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(image)

Next b
```

Comment: I have no idea why this was voted down; Guffa is completely correct here. The name of the variable is irrelevant, since it only exists within the context of a single iteration of the loop anyway. Additionally, carpenter's original code in the question itself is creating an array in each iteration of the loop for absolutely no reason!